# Why does addEventListener not work for radio button's focus event in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Consider the following example (also available here: http://jsfiddle.net/hq8Fg/1/).  It works fine in IE9, but doesn't work in Chrome 16.

In IE, if I click on the radio button, I see the message, but in Chrome nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nothing</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function begin() {
    var rb1 = document.getElementById('rb1');
    rb1.addEventListener('focus', function() { document.getElementById("theText").value = "focus"; }, false);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="begin()">
    <input id="rb1" type="radio" />
    <textarea id="theText"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why it's not working in Chrome and what I can do to fix it?

p.s. I know I can probably use a library like JQuery, but I want to know if it's possible without using any libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `onclick` event since the problem isn't that the event is not called when the element gets focused; The problem is that it is really not focused on click. You can figure that out through focusing your textarea and then pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [less than stellar source](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/dom/radio-events.php), the focus event for a radio button is only supposed to fire when you *tab* into it, which you can see in your fiddle.

I'll see if I can find some better documentation of this—MDN ideally.

**EDIT**

From [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection)

> **Changing the focus**
>
> There are several ways to change the currently focused element. The
>   simplest is to call the focus method of a the XUL element that you
>   wish to set the focus to. The blur method can be used to remove the
>   focus from an element. The following example demonstrates this:
>
> Example 5 : Source View
>
> `<button label="Focus"
>   oncommand="document.getElementById('addr').focus()"/>` Or, you can use
>   the methods advanceFocus and rewindFocus on the command dispatcher.
>   These methods move the focus to the next element in sequence or the
>   previous element respectively. **This is what happens when the user
>   presses TAB or Shift+Tab.**
>
> For textboxes, a special attribute, focused is added whenever the
>   element has the focus. You can check for the presence of this
>   attribute to determine if the element has the focus, either from a
>   script or within a style sheet. It will have the value true if the
>   textbox has the focus and, if the textbox does not have the focus, the
>   attribute will not be present.
>
> Suppose you wanted to move the focus from where it currently is, to
>   the next place the browser thinks it should be. A user typically does
>   this by hitting the "Tab" key. You can do this anywhere you have a XUL
>   browser document by simply:

(emphasis mine)

Comment: The linked and copied MDN article is about [XUL (XML User Interface Language)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL), used internally by Firefox. It is not the same as the [DOM (Document Object Model)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) used in web pages.

Comment: For a better source, see the W3C documentation about [`onfocus`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onfocus): "The onfocus event occurs when an element receives focus either by the **pointing device** or by tabbing navigation." This indicates that the focus event should be available when clicking a radio button, unless an exception exists. (Did not find one as easily.)

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, the focus event only fires for a radio button when the keyboard is used to navigate to a radio button.  For clicking on the radio button, use the click event like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XatCv/